# How to use Class Library in Asp.Net mvc 5 Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2019

I'm developing a Asp.Net MVC5 Application.I have created 3 Projects inside a solution .

1. C# class Library -Domain Model
2. Asp.Net MVC Application
3. Unit Test project

The Problem is when I am trying to use Domain class file into Asp.Net MVC Application errors are coming.I unable to use the domain namespace in Asp.Net MVC Application project.

using SportsStore.Domain.Abstract;
using SportsStore.Domain.Entities;

this are the name spaces try to use inside Asp.Net MVC Application 
Here-Abstract and Entities are folder inside the class Library-Domain

```
using SportsStore.Domain.Abstract;
using SportsStore.Domain.Entities;        

private void AddBindings()
        {
            Mock<IProductRepository> mock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
            mock.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(new List<Product>
            {
                new Product { Name = "Football", Price = 25 },
                new Product { Name = "Surf board", Price = 179 },
                new Product { Name = "Running shoes", Price = 95 }
            });
            kernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().ToConstant(mock.Object);
        }
```

This codes are for IDependencyResolver Making a Mock Repository

I unable to add that AddBindings

Comment: do you reference the project lib in your MVC proj?

Comment: What project library do I have to add to My MVC Project?

Comment: I already add  references to my Domain class Library ,I didn't any reference to mvc proj

Comment: ok .. if yiu check the dll in your MVC dependencies ... does it show a warning?

Comment: How to check for warning ,I did'nt find any warnings

Answer (score 0):

you have to add reference to class library first then you'll be able to bring namespaces. Right-click on reference file in class library there we will come projects
tab then select your mvc project there.